# How to handle concurrent changes in objects of different classes in Java (or how might I improve my design :)

Tags: java, oop, architecture, implementation

I am trying to implement a directory tree in java. I need to implement two different classes: `Dir` and `File`. Each directory object, of type `Dir`, contains a collection with the files it contains, and another one with its children directories, implemented as follows:

```
public class Dir {
  private List<Dir> childrenDirectories;
  private List<File> files;
}
```

Each file object, of type `File`, contains its parent directory:

```
public class File {
  private Dir parentDirectory
}
```

I would not like for these attributes to be accessed to from `main()`, as this would open up the possibility for someone to improperly manipulate these attributes. This would require their visibility, as well as their getters' and setters', to be set to protected or private.
Now, for the consistency of the tree structure, when a file is inserted into a directory (through a method `Dir.put(File)`), two things need to happen: the file should be included in the list `Dir.files`, and the directory into the attribute `File.parentDirectory`.
My problem with this implementation is that there is no place where both `Dir.files` and `File.parentDirectory` are visible, and so the method `Dir.put(File)` cannot exist anywhere. I guess this is a problem with my design, but I fail to come up with something better.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

A design that came to mind is to set `File.parentDirectory` as protected, and make the class `Dir` extend the class `File`. This would make this attribute visible from inside `Dir`, and the method `Dir.put(File)` could then access it.
There are a couple of problems that come to mind with this implementation:
First, and least critical, a directory is not a type of file (I don't think). I understand inheritance in a program has to correspond to a reality, and this one would not.
Also, each `Dir` object would have an attribute `parentDirectory` (inherited from the `File` class), which would be unused. This is wasteful, especially when you consider that, once implemented properly, a `File` object would have many other attributes I can't use in a `Dir` object.
Finally, and most importantly, this offers the possibility for a method inside `Dir` to access protected attributes and methods of the `File` class, but not the other way around, which is a problem I will run into when I try to implement, for example, a function `File.delete()`, which should remove the file from the directory it is in.

Comment: Dir and File should be part of the same package, which then grants the required access.  'package access' is, loosely speaking, about the same as protected access but for classes in the same package rather than for descendent classes.

Comment: Since every `Dir` has a list of `childrenDirectories`, it’s weird that you say a `Dir` should not have a `parentDirectory`. And speaking of file systems of operating systems, directories *are* files and have all of their attributes.

Answer (score 0):

A File & a Directory are essentially the same as they share most of the attributes and behaviour. So it may not make sense to model them as separate entities.

Keeping it simple, a tree like structure may be the way to go -

```
public class FileNode {
    
    List<FileNode> children;
    
    FileNode parent;
    
    
    public void deleteSelf() {
        /**
         * Should be good enough to delete self and children, if children are applicable
         * (Make sure your equals/hashCode are appropriately defined)
         */
        getParent().getChildren().remove(this);
        
    }
    
    public boolean isDir() {
        //Make a default call to the java.io.filesystem to figure this out.
        return false;
    }

    public List<FileNode> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    public void setChildren(List<FileNode> children) {
        this.children = children;
    }

    public FileNode getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(FileNode parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }
    
    

}
```

Here FileNode is both a File & Dir.